# Android: How to determine a given url is video link or a webpage

Tags: android-webview

**How to determine that a given link is video or a weblink...as all link dont have extension as .mp4 or .3gp etc....viz
http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=comedy&aq=f (is a weblink)
[http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vt4X7zFfv4k][1] (is a video link)
In order to call respective view as video or webview...**

Answer (score 0):

The only way to be sure is to get the head of the url, follow all redirects and check the mimetype of the response.

Comment: Thank you for your help.... Hii i tried following:

String texturl="vnd.youtube:x6nVGm_0DPE?
vndapp=youtube_mobile&vndclient=mv-google&vndel=index";

URL url2;

String contentType = null;

try {

url2 = new URL(texturl);

try {

contentType = ((HttpURLConnection) 
url2.openConnection()).getContentType(); }

catch (IOException e) {

Log.d("content type: ", contentType); }

catch (MalformedURLException e) { //sth.

Error: 07-20 16:49:18.901: WARN/System.err(446): java.net.MalformedURLException: Unknown protocol: vnd.youtube

Please suggest how to follow redirects....!!!